# Jetty 7.4.2 + Quercus 4.0.18: How can I read PHP files from outside the webapp directory

Tags: java, php, jetty, quercus

Using this code...

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class OneWebApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String jetty_home = "C:/Software/jetty";

        Server server = new Server(8080);

        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
        webapp.setContextPath("/");
        webapp.setWar(jetty_home+"/quercus-4.0.18.war");
        server.setHandler(webapp);

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

... I can read PHP files from the webapp directory: C:\Documents and Settings\mydir\Local Settings\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-quercus-4.0.18.war-_-any-\webapp

How can I configure Jetty to look for the PHP files in another directory? For example: `C:\Projects\phpfiles`

With Apache, I would simply do something like this in the config:

```
Alias /phpfiles "C:\Projects\phpfiles"
<Directory C:\Projects\phpfiles>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: What is it exactly you need to do?

Comment: I want to serve the PHP files from outside the temp dir the web app is deployed in.  I want Jetty to look in  a different directory for the web resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the war path to:

```
[...]
webapp.setContextPath("/");
webapp.setWar("C:/Projects/phpfiles");
[...]
```

The directory phpfiles will need to contains the structure of a web application (minimally include *WEB-INF/web.xml*). You'll need to either include the quercus dependencies in *WEB-INF/lib* or simply add the dependencies in your classpath (since it's embedded). The dependencies and *web.xml* can be found in *quercus-*.war*.

If you need to have multiple source directories of php files, which I don't think is support. You would need to extends **[QuercusServletImpl](http://www.caucho.com/resin-4.0-javadoc/com/caucho/quercus/servlet/QuercusServletImpl.html)** and implement/override *getPath(HttpServletRequest req)*.

Comment: I want to deploy the war in one place and pull the PHP files from another, so the first option is no good.  I'll look into extending QuercusServletImpl.